# What's the best / most efficient way to updated a sub-model/property in a parent model/property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So say I have `ClassA` which has properties:

```
//ClassA
int ID
string Name
ClassB SubModel
```

And I also have `ClassB` which has properties:

```
//ClassB
int ID
string Name
```

Now I have a view where the user can modify `ClassA` as well as `ClassA`'s associated `ClassB` property.

What is the best way to go about modifying `ClassB`?

Right now, when I retrieve `ClassA`, I do a `.Include` to retrieve its `ClassB` and when I expose the properties to the user, I do `ClassA.SubModel.Name`, etc.

Is this the correct way to do it? Or should I grab `ClassA` and it's `ClassB` separately and have them as two separate properties and when I update, call two updates to update them individually?

Comment: What makes you think there is a single "best" way?

Comment: You could create a new `ClassC` which would be your model for that operation/view, it would be an amalgamation of `ClassA` and `ClassB`. That way you are only dealing with a flat class in the view and you can translate/map to your persistent classes in your controller. Look up POCO classes.

Answer (score 1):

The "best" way to do this is pretty subjective but one commonly used method to accomplish this is to use a .Include when retrieving the data you need for your view (as you mentioned you're doing above) then in the view you can use Html helpers and a form post like the following to post the edited data back to the controller:

```
@model MyApplication.ViewModels.ClassA

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SubModel.Name)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

The HTML helpers will help format the html name attributes for your properties appropriately so that data is serialized properly from the view to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single "best" way to accomplish this. It all depends on your business. Hence I just share how I would do it.

#### My DDD Approach

In my Domain-Drive Design practice project, I have 2 sets of models, not including view models for views:

- Domain models - represent your business logic, not depend on your infrastructure code
- Persistence models - represent how you map the domain models in the database of your choice

#### Persistence Models

I can define `ClassA` and `ClassB` as entities with one-to-many relationship.

Let's say I use `Entity Framework Core` as the ORM and `SQL Server` as the database.

```
public class ClassAEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ClassBId { get; set; }
    public ClassBEntity ClassB { get; set; }
}

public class ClassBEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ClassAEntity> ClassAs { get; set; }
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options): base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Configure relationships
        builder.Entity<ClassAEntity>(b =>
        {
            b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            b.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();

            b.HasOne(x => x.ClassB)
                .WithMany(y => y.ClassAs)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ClassBId);

            b.ToTable("ClassA");
        });

        builder.Entity<ClassBEntity>(b =>
        {
            b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            b.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();

            b.ToTable("ClassB");
        });
    }

    public DbSet<ClassAEntity> ClassAs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClassBEntity> ClassBs { get; set; }
}
```

#### Domain Models

You can construct your domain models totally different from how you construct your persistence models. In fact in my project, `ClassA` and `ClassB` are in two separate namespaces and they're both the `Aggregate Root`s - they are not allowed to reference each other directly. They can only refer each other by their identities. Also you see those private setters?

```
public class ClassA : AggregateRoot
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public int ClassBId { get; private set; }

    private ClassA() { }

    private ClassA(CreateClassACommand command) : base(command.Id)
    {
        this.Name = command.Name;
        this.ClassBId = command.ClassBId;

        // You can create events and store them later on as auditing or
        // have others subscribe this event. 
        AddEvent(new ClassACreated
        {
            // ...
        });
    }

    public static ClassA CreateNew(CreateClassACommand command,
        IValidator<CreateClassACommand> validator)
    {
        // You can have validations here too, with help of FluentValidation
        // library
        validator.ValidateAndThrow(command);

        return new ClassA(command);
    }

    public void UpdateDetails(UpdateClassADetailsCommand command,
        IValidator<UpdateClassADetailsCommand> validator)
    {
        validator.ValidateAndThrow(command);

        this.Name = command.Name;
        this.ClassBId = command.SelectedClassBId;

        AddEvent(new ClassADetailsUpdated 
        {
            // ...
        });
    }
}
```

Hopefully you see the benefits of having a class to represent your business logic. You can have private setters there to prevent data from being changed by other classes. You can define methods open to others which have validations in place.

#### Edit Screen(s)

Since my `ClassA` and `ClassB` are two separate aggregates, I didn't plan to have a screen to update them at the same time. Instead, I have 2 separate controllers to represent them.

On editing `ClassA` screen, I can provide a list of available `ClassBs` as dropdown since their relationship is one-to-many.

Again, there is no right way. It all depends on your business logic.

```
public ClassAController : AdminControllerBase
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public ClassAController(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        // Find the entity by id in the database
        var classAEntity = _dbContext.ClassAs
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (classAEntity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        // Find a list of available class Bs
        var availableClassBs = _dbContext.ClassBs
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => ... your filter ...)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);

        // Construct the view model for editing
        var vm = new EditClassAViewModel
        {
            ClassAId = classAEntity.Id,
            Name = classAEntity.Name,
            SelectedClassBId = classAEntity.ClassBId,
            AvailableClassBs = availableClassBs
        };

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

Here is the view model for the editing screen. Depends on what you want to be editable, you can construct properties for that purpose. Also this is the right place to put your data annotations, if you have client-side validation enabled.

```
public class EditClassAViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int ClassAId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Class b")]
    public int SelectedClassBId { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<int, string> AvailableClassBs { get; set; }
}
```

#### Edit ClassA View

I think you get the idea here so I am not going to post any example of the view, to save some spaces.

#### On Submit

On post back, the controller captures the view model, and then you can convert it to your domain model, call the right action off the domain model, which will handle validations on its own, and then at the end, you convert your domain model to your persistence model and save it back to the database.

Note: in my project, I used MediatR library - send and handle requests/commands, AutoMapper library - convert models back and forth, and repository pattern but here I just put everything together to simplify the process.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(EditClassAViewModel model)
{
    var response = new JsonResponse();
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        response.AddModalStateErrors(ModelState);
        return Json(response);
    }

    // Get the ClassA entity from the database and convert the persistence
    // model to your domain model. You could have your repository to do
    // both in one step.
    var classAEntity = _dbContext.ClassAs
        .AsNoTracking()
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.ClassAId);
    if (classAEntity == null)
    {
        response.AddError(...);
        return Json(response);
    }

    // Convert the persistence model to domain model. You could use
    // AutoMapper to do so.
    var classA = new ClassA(...);

    // Class the ClassA domain model UpdateDetails method
    classA.UpdateDetails(...);

    // Convert the domain model back to persistence model
    // and save it to the database. You could have your repository to do
    // both in one step.
    var classAPersistenceModel = ...;

    // Since this persistence model is not tracked by EFCore,
    // you need to fetch the entity again from database by Id and update
    // that entity instead.
    // Again, you could have your repository to do that in one step too.
    classAEntity = _dbContext.ClassAs.Find(classAPersistenceModel.Id);
    if (classAEntity != null)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(classAEntity).CurrentValues
            .SetValues(classAPersistenceModel);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Disclaim: Yea I know there might be many new stuff I ignored in this post, i.e., Request/Command pattern using IMediatR, validation using FluentValidation, AutoMapper configuration, and repository pattern. But the focus of this post is just to give you insights of my DDD approach. XD